# How can I avoid a reported conflict when moving an explicit interface implementation into a derived class in ReSharper?

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper, automated-refactoring

Given the following code

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyExampleDerived : MyExampleBase
    {
        public int MyAnswer()
        {
            return 42;
        }
    }

    class MyExampleBase : IMyInterface
    {
        int IMyInterface.MyAnswer()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    interface IMyInterface
    {
        int MyAnswer();
    }
}
```

If I try moving `IMyInterface` and `IMyInterface.MyAnswer` from the base class to the derived class using "Push Members Down", I get the following notification of an error level severity conflict:

[image: Resharper Conflict found]

```
MyExampleChild.cs
  MyNamespace.MyExampleDerived.MyAnswer declared in the target element has conflicts with moved members
    (5,14) public int MyAnswer()
```

If I continue with it, there's no compilation errors for the code, even though the documentation [Resolve conflicts in refactorings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Resolving_Conflicts_in_Refactorings.html) indicates that a conflict with a "no entry" icon should cause the compilation to fail.

Is there anything wrong with such a move, and if not, how can I make ReSharper not report it as a conflict?

(Yes, I could just ignore it saying that there's a conflict, but my actual refactorings would have multiple conflicts reported, and false alarms make it harder to notice real problems)

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior with R# 2023.2. After I push `MyExampleBase.MyAnswer` down to `MyExampleDerived`, I get two `MyAnswer` implementations inside `MyExampleDerived`, which is what the conflict dialog warns about.